# Unable to upload Draft APK to test in-app billing - we get an error message indicating it assumes we want to publish

Tags: android, apk

We have followed the instructions at http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-real to introduce in-app billing to our application, and now want to add our live product IDs.

As per the instructions, we build our APK with the necessary permissions and sign the APK.  Once the upload is complete, we get the following error :

"This configuration cannot be published for the following reasons :  All devices that might receive version 3001 would receive version 3002."

We do NOT want to publish this APK, but only upload it as a Draft APK, in order to complete testing of IAP.

Does anyone have a workaround to this?

Comment: check your in app product...whether it is published or not ?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around this problem by switching back to the old version of the Developer Console and then deactivating my one older version, after which I deleted that older version and saved the app.  Upon returning the the new version of the Console, the problem was resolved.

However, I believe the old version of the console will soon become unavailable, so this approach may not be available much longer.

Answer (score 1):

Deactivate the old version first and then you should be able to publish the new version of the app.

Comment: Man, you just saved my night. This is the wright answer, and it seems SO obvious now that I know it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Switch to the old version and update the new apk...

It works for me.

Thanks Carl